# Node.js program failing to read .log text file with Buffer error

Tags: logging, log-files, node.js, buffer

I am attempting to view a log with a program called 'logger'. When I run `node logger` I get the following error:

```
<Buffer 66 72 75 69 74 69 73 68 79 0a>
```

The 'logger' program file looks as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createReadStream("veg.log");

file.on('readable', function() {
    var stream = null;
    while(null !== (stream = file.read()))  {
      stream.toString();
      console.log(stream);
      }
});
```

Does anyone have an idea what's causing the error? The log file is just plain text. Why is this causing an error with my buffer and how do I find out which buffer it is and what's causing it to be incorrectly accessed?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical procedure is to use a buffer to collect chunks of data by listening to `on('data')` events. When the stream is finished, the `on('end')` event will be emitted, and then you can do something with the buffer.

This code should do what you need:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var buffer = '';
var file = fs.createReadStream("veg.log");
file.on('data', function(chunk) {
  buffer += chunk;
});
file.on('end', function () {
  console.log(buffer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a buffer option for the `createReadStream` function. Like so:

```
var file = fs.createReadStream("veg.log", "utf8");
```